# Threading and synchronized methods

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization

I have the following code:

```
public class MyThread extends Thread {
    private int i;
    public static int sum=0;
    public MyThread(int k){
      i=k;
    }




    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException{

       Thread t=new MyThread(1);
       Thread s=new MyThread(2);
       Thread p=new MyThread(3);
       t.start();
       s.start();       
    }


public synchronized void doSomething(){
    for(int i=0; i<100000; i++){
        System.out.println(this.i);
    }

}

    @Override
    public void run() {
        doSomething();

    }
}
```

the doSomething is synchronized. why is the output random?
My assumption that the synchronized method would be the same as the synchronized block but the output of the block is sync and the method  isn't.

Comment: What do you mean by 'random'? From the code it appears that you have 3 threads running, each will be allocated processor time and the output will therefore be interleaved.

Answer (score 9):

The `synchronized` keyword there prevents synchronized method calls on *the same object* from being interleaved. It does not prevent interleaving method calls on *different* objects. Since you have three different objects, the three calls can run simultaneously.

You need to synchronize on a single object which is shared by all three threads.

Answer (score 1):

The synchronization on methods only holds for invocations of the same object. You are creating two different objects (the two threads).

Answer (score 0):

The lock used by `synchronized` methods is associated with an instance of class `MyThread`. Since each thread has its own instance `MyThread`, each thread is synchronizing on its own lock.

If you wanted to synchronize across all threads, you could do something along the lines of:

```
public class MyThread extends Thread {

    private static final Object sharedLock = new Object();

    public void doSomething() {
      synchronized(sharedLock) {
        for(int i=0; i<100000; i++) {
          System.out.println(this.i);
        }
      }
    }
    ...
 }
```

An alternative is to `synchronize` on `MyThread.class`, but I prefer the first approach.

In the comments you say that if you change your code to use `synchronized(this)` in `doSomething`, all of a sudden it works. I am pretty sure it doesn't. It may have worked by chance, but it won't work repeatedly and reliably.

Comment: but if I change it to synchronized(this) and put the loop inside it does get the ordered results, but the synchronization is on the instance of the class of mythread